# Cloud custodian GCP storage enable versioning check for all storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloudcustodian

i am trying to write GCP storage bucket policy of Cloud custodian but not getting idea how to filter out the versioning on all avilable buckets

```
policies:
  - name: check-all-bucket-versioning
    description: |
      Check all bucket versionig enabled
    resource: gcp.bucket
    filters:
      - type: value
        key: versioning
        value: true
    actions:
```

any help would be really helpful..!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example policy is very close. It is failing because the value for `versioning` is an object rather than a string. When versioning is enabled for a bucket, the `versioning` value will be `{"enabled": True}`. We can filter for that by using `versioning.enabled` as the key:

```
policies:
  - name: check-all-bucket-versioning
    resource: gcp.bucket
    filters:
      - type: value
        key: versioning.enabled
        value: true
```